# Where Can I Find Van der Waerden's Modern Algebra, Volume I, Chapter 5 Online?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, reference-request, resultant

I am looking for an electronic copy of Van der Waerden's *Modern Algebra*, Volume 1, Chapter 5. Due to the pandemic, I can't get it from a library.

I am not an expert on copyright law, but my understanding is that it is legal to copy one chapter. Specifically, I would like to see pages 106 and 107 of the 7th edition, but perhaps I will need to see earlier pages to understand what is on those two pages.

I am actually interested in introductory but extensive accounts discussing resultants of polynomials.

I certainly would not ever encourage anyone to post a link to the entire book in a comment, to be deleted soon afterwards, leaving no trace for Scotland Yard to follow.

Comment: I’m sure that that book is in the public domain now.

Comment: Even if someone posted the whole book, and then deleted the comment (a complete hypothetical, of course), moderators could still see the comment. There is no evading Scotland Yard. :)

Answer (score 1):

[A copy](https://archive.org/details/modernalgebrainp0001waer/page/n5/mode/2up) is available for borrowing from the Internet Archive.  To borrow a copy you'll need to register, which is free. [Van der Waerden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartel_Leendert_van_der_Waerden) died in 1996, so the copyright will not expire in Australia (where I live), or Europe, until the end of 2066.  I would presume the Internet Archive has obtained permission to make it available for borrowing.  You'd need to check the copyright laws in your own country to find out how much of the book you're legally entitled to copy.